# How to display tool tip for each cell?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I modify the code to display each cell information into a tooltip??

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_post_init.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/*
* First step is to create title attributes for the rows in the table
* This isn't needed if the required 'title' attribute is already set in the HTML in the
* DOM
*/
$('#example tbody tr').each( function() {
var sTitle;
var nTds = $('td', this);
var sBrowser = $(nTds[1]).text();
var sGrade = $(nTds[4]).text();

if ( sGrade == "A" )
sTitle = sBrowser+' will provide a first class (A) level of CSS support.';
else if ( sGrade == "C" )
sTitle = sBrowser+' will provide a core (C) level of CSS support.';
else if ( sGrade == "X" )
sTitle = sBrowser+' does not provide CSS support or has a broken implementation. Block CSS.';
else
sTitle = sBrowser+' will provide an undefined level of CSS support.';

this.setAttribute( 'title', sTitle );
} );

/* Init DataTables */
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

/* Apply the tooltips */
oTable.$('tr').tooltip( {
"delay": 0,
"track": true,
"fade": 250
} );
} );
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do

```
{ "sTitle": "...", ...
   'fnCreatedCell': function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
        nTd.title = 'Some more information';
   }
}
```

in your column configuration. You can use all the row data easily like this.
Of cause, this must not be missing:

```
oTable.$('td').tooltip( {
    "delay": 0,
    "track": true,
    "fade": 100
} );
```

Comment: Fantastic little tip there!  I have been working w/datatables recently, and it is amazingly robust.  My only question, how does this actually work?  Why is setting title enough to expose a tooltip?  I am confused by that.

Comment: Hi rkd80, tooltip is a jQuery UI component (https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) which will read the title attribute. "oTable.$('td').tooltip(..." tells the tooltip component to show the tooltip for every td element in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can set title by simply setAttribute for each td

```
 $('#example tbody tr td').each( function() {
    this.setAttribute( 'title', $(this).text());
});
```

and call tooltip on td

```
oTable.$('td').tooltip( {
"delay": 0,
"track": true,
"fade": 250
} );
```

Comment: Yup. And if the tooltip's contents aren't meant to be the text, you could theoretically retrieve other information from elsewhere (for example, a data- attribute) using essentially the same technique.